# Custom X and Y-axis range for lineChart with python-nvd3

Tags: python, charts, python-nvd3

This is a simple `lineChart` example using `python-nvd3`:

```
from nvd3 import lineChart
chart = lineChart(width=600)

xdata = range(13)
ydata = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 11, 10, 8, 5, 4, 2, 1]

chart.add_serie(y=ydata, x=xdata)
chart.buildhtml()

with open('plot.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(chart.htmlcontent)
```

By default, the range of values of the X and Y-axis is derived from the minimum and maximum values of `xdata` and `ydata`, thus X is from 0 to 12 and Y is from 1 to 11. The rendered plot in `plot.html` looks like this:

[image]

How can I modify the code above to define a custom range for X and Y-axis for a given `xdata` & `ydata`? For instance, set Y from 0 to 12 and X from -1 to 13.

Comment: Have you checked if there are similar options for python-nvd3? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43555098/6235557

Comment: I have, but I didn't find anything. `python-nvd3` seems to be more limited compared to `NVD3`...